# How to debug a swing UI?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have a Swing screen and I want to debug which services or frames are being used by it. Earlier I have worked on Web apps and there we used used FireBug in firefox mozilla to see how things used in UI and navigate to services. I am new to swing and want to find out how this new application is using it.

Comment: I have never tried it myself, but it looks like http://www.swinginspector.com/index_en.htm should do the job. On a side note, if this is a **new** application, do not use Swing - use JavaFX instead.

Comment: Andreas's link is no longer relevant as It points to a non java site.

Answer (score 15):

Here is the debug swing is [Debugging Swing Applications with the UI Debugger](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/ui-debuger-087839.html) it can be quite useful to debug Swing related application.

Another one [Visual Debugger](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/debug-visual.html) provided by NetBeans .

The [swinginspector](http://www.swinginspector.com/index_en.htm) is a Java Swing/AWT user interface analysis and debugging tools, features, and similar firebug, powerful Swing/AWT user interface analysis and debugging function.

Here another thing i found

> When your JFrame is visible press CTRL+SHIFT+F1 and see the console
>   output for the tree hierarchy of components and layouts.

Comment: I have to give you a +1 for showing me something new, +15 years in Swing development and didn't know those two last tools event existed!

Comment: @MadProgrammer NP sometimes we missed some good things also :)

Comment: @SubodhJoshi i was thinking of using swing explorer and it seesm to fit the problme i am having. But i cannot get swing explorer plugin for eclipse. All the download links are pointing to a site which is not existing. ANy idea?

Comment: @shrutirawat I was also checking for that before adding answer ,even IBM website have a post http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-swingtest/  but look like that project closed.

Comment: The links above are partly broken. Better search the tools by name instead.